# Java Communication netty server - Socket client

Tags: java, sockets, netty

For a chat server project I use netty as server, with the following code in my handler :

```
public class PacketHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{

        @Override
        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
            ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
            try {
                AbstractClientPacket packet = ClientPacketHandler.handle(in);
                if(packet != null && packet.read()){
                    packet.run();
                    ctx.write(msg+"\r\n");
                }
            } finally {
                ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
            cause.printStackTrace();
            ctx.close();
        }
}
```

So, my packet is correctly handled and it works fine, but then, i do `ctx.write(msg+"\r\n");` to send back the message to my client, acting like an echo server.

Here is the Client's code :

```
public class ChatClient {

    static Socket socket;
    static DataOutputStream out;
    static BufferedReader in;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            initSocket();

            String test = "Salut 1";

            TestPacket packet = new TestPacket(0x18,test.getBytes());

            sendPacket(packet);

            while(true){
                try {

                    String message = in.readLine();
                    System.out.println(message);

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            //TEST
        } catch (IOException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void initSocket(){
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost",58008);
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((socket.getInputStream())));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void sendPacket(TestPacket p) throws IOException{
        out.write(p.getRawData());
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

The packet is correctly sent, but i get nothing as reply, and when i stop my server, the client is spamming null because of my `while(true)`, but i don't get my message back, nothing is displayed and i really don't know why.

I can't use netty for the client because this one is just for test purpose, the final client will be written in C# (Unity Engine), so i can't use netty in this one, I have to do it with native socket handling.

EDIT:

According to wireshark, The packet from client is sent but the server answer is not, i don't see the packet From server containing "Salut 1".

Comment: I tried to flush after doing `ctx.write()` but still same problem.

Comment: `readLine()` returns null at end of stream, which happens when the peer disconnects. You need to test for that, and break, and close the connection, when you get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did:

```
ctx.write(msg+"\r\n");
```

`msg` is not a `String` but a `ByteBuf`. If you want to append `\r\n` to the received message, you should do the following:

```
in.writeByte('\r');
in.writeByte('\n');
ctx.write(in);
```

Also, because you reused the received message (`in`) as a response, you should not release it:

```
// Do NOT call this.
ReferenceCountUtil.release(in);
```

If you really intended to call `ctx.write(msg + "\r\n")`, please make sure that your pipeline has `StringEncoder`.

Comment: in fact the problem was coming from the `finally` part of the try block, the release was making me unable to reply correctly.